# Cálculo dos dias de um mês

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou montando uma agenda e vou fazer um calendário. Preciso saber quantos dias tem no mês e também que dia da semana é o dia 1º de cada mês. Como fazer isso com PHP?

Comment: achei estes exemplos meio prontos: http://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar http://www.php-calendar.org/

Comment: fullCalendar é uma lib muito boa, simples e com uma boa documentação.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta, acho que ficou mais fácil de responder agora!!! aguardo mais respostas...

Comment: Porque usou as tags jQuery e JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

Isso pode não responder completamente tua pergunta, mas usei uma vez a biblioteca [Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) para datas e funcionou muito bem.

É um biblioteca em jQuery de uma interface estilo Google Calendar, toda com *drag-and-drop*, tem [uma demo](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR) do que pode ser feito com ela.

Para processar os dados gerados por funções de callback tipo:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
  dayClick: function() {
    alert('a day has been clicked!'); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Baseado em um modelo que postaram eu criei esse calendário simples:

```
<?php 
    $month = 8;
    $year = 2014;
    $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));

    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
    echo "<div id=\"calendario_dia\">$list_day</div>";
    endfor;
?>
```

Precisa ser modificado para ficar "usavel", é só a base que eu precisava!!!

Comment: Acredito que esta é uma resposta a que o usuário chegou sozinho. Se for este caso, seria melhor marcá-la como certa.